# Does Jameson define "narrative" anywhere?

Tags: marxism

Does Jameson define "narrative" anywhere? I've read the political unconscious, and just ordered a study of him, and I would probably agree that narratives embody social reality, but am unclear what counts as a narrative.

Examples in the secondary literature include myths, stories, and the plots of soap operas. But I believe history itself isn't a narrative?

Comment: According to [Wegner's Periodizing Jameson](https://escholarship.org/content/qt4b96m8bf/qt4b96m8bf.pdf):"*Jameson  characterizes  narrative  as  a  mode  of  presentation — or  to  use  the  “untranslatable”  German  term  that  is  so  important  for  his  project,  
Darstellung — taking  the  form  of  a  “rhetorical  movement  of  language and  writing  through  time”*".

Comment: Wegner takes as epigraph a quote from The Ideologies of Theory:"*The “desire for Marx” can therefore also be called a desire for narrative, if by this we understand, not some vacuous concept of “linearity” or even telos, but rather the impossible attempt to give representation to the multiple and incommensurable temporalities in which each of us exists.*"

Comment: i think someone is just being vindictive to downvote this haha

Comment: Seems a reasonable question to me. +1.

Comment: See [Narratology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narratology) and [Literary Theory](https://www.iep.utm.edu/literary/). IMO, Jameson does not use "narrative" in any "technical" sense; see e.g. [Postmodernism](https://books.google.it/books?id=oRJ9fh9BK8wC&printsec=frontcover).